# Replacing an ISA CAN Bus Card

Tags: windows, drivers

Having a third party system using an Advantech PCL-841 (16 Bit ISA Card) and want to replace it with an Advantech PCIE-1680 Card (PCI Express).

Does the Application (no source code available need to get modified or is there some API compatibility?)

The App is written in 32 Bit Visual Basic 6, is it possible to use Windows 10 Pro x64 Bit ? Is Driver Access from 32 Bit (APP) to 64 Bit (OS) compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Basic runtime will work on Windows 10.

> The Visual Basic team is committed to “It Just Works” compatibility
>   for Visual Basic 6.0 applications on the following supported Windows
>   operating systems: Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008 including R2,
>   Windows 7, Windows 8 and Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 including
>   R2, and Windows 10.

In the OS, even if x64, it will work in emulation mode. (*32bit apps running in WOW only*)

> Visual Basic 6.0 runtime files are 32-bit. These files ship in 64-bit
>   Windows Operating Systems referenced in the table below. 32-bit VB6
>   applications and components are supported in the WOW emulation
>   environment only. 32-bit components must also be hosted in 32-bit
>   application processes.
>
> The Visual Basic 6.0 IDE has never been offered in a native 64-bit
>   version, nor has the 32-bit IDE been supported on 64-bit Windows. VB6
>   development on 64-bit Windows or any native architecture other than
>   32-bit is not and will not be supported.

What worry me the most is your controller as I got no idea to what it connect to. Does the gear it connect too is compatible too ? Does you tested it ?

Your best solution for your question is to test/lab it as a machine with Windows 10 is easy to get your hand on it, and you can keep your old computer ready in case your test does not work.

If you do all those step be sure to write what you do, as if it's a critical application you will have a migration plan ready after.

Comment: The controller is expensive. So I asked before ordering it, cannot return it :-(

Comment: Does a Win64 Driver always support Win32 Apps in WOW32 Mode?

Comment: @NickD Windows 10 exist in x86 if that help :)

Comment: @NickD The question I have is the card, the old app use what API to connect to it, is both card got the same API ? , etc..

Comment: Don't know this. Vendor does not respond to any enquiries :-/

Comment: @NickD maybe check with another vendor, if ingram or a big distributor got that part, you could order it via another store, and ask the store if they can retake it with a restocking fee (like a 30% restocking)